# "When a girl of twenty marries a man close to eighty it is obvious that she is marrying him for money"

Tags: tense

> When a girl of twenty marries a man close to eighty it is obvious that she is marrying him for money

I was wondering why marrying after "marries", is there a rule?

Comment: The present continuous sometimes indicates the speaker's disapproval, annoyance. *"Oh, she is always dating guys with money. She is so shallow!"* However, I don't think there is a rule, you could also say the main clause in the present tense..

Comment: Also, because when a girl of 20 marries a man over 80 (*present tense for general fact*) it is obvious **at the moment that she is marrying him** (present continuous for being in the middle of an action).

Comment: Can we say when we use the progressive tense there is always a meaning of in the middle of something?

Comment: @mandel  Usually, yes.  *I eat fish* = I do this regularly.  *I am eating fish* = I am doing this right now.  But it can also sometimes be used in other way, like indicating exasperation, as in *You're always interrupting me when I'm working!*